# Line Weight of Marker Outline versus Series Line

Tags: vba, excel

For a line chart, in the Excel UI:

- You can manually change the line weight of the series line in 'Format Data Series', Line Style.
- You can manually change the line weight of the marker outline in 'Format Data Series', Marker Line Style.

I haven't been able to distinguish these two in the VBA object model. For example, if you change each one in sequence while recording, the code is as follows:

```
With Selection.Format.Line ' This block is from Line Style
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 1.5
End With
With Selection.Format.Line ' This block is from Marker Line Style
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Weight = 2
End With
```

I want to write VBA code that will make the line between points thicker (like, 2 points), and the line around the point itself thinner (like 1 point). But if I use the code like above, changing one will change the other as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Let me restate the desired end result: I want all line segments between points to be thicker, and all lines around the points to be thinner. (It can be achieved with the UI, but I haven't found a way to do it with code). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you have found a solution yet. I am facing the exact same issue.

Comment: Hi Charlie! Sorry, I haven't

Comment: I think @Excel Developers had the right idea, refer to the objects directly, instead of `With Selection` which is ambiguous context. Even so, it appears that `.Format.Line` for `SeriesCollection(n)` and `.SeriesCollection(n).Point` are linked: one clobbers the other (on a per-point basis), regardless of which order you put them in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a possible solution:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select

With Selection
   .Format.Line.Weight = 2 'Sets thickness = 2 to markers-line and series-line 
   .Border.Weight = xlHairLine 'Sets thickness = 0.25 to the series-line    
   .Border.Weight = xlThin 'Sets thickness = 1 to the series-line
   .Border.Weight = xlMedium 'Sets thickness = 2 to the series-line
   .Border.Weight = xlThick  'Sets thickness = 3 to the series-line
End With
```

This way you can set any weight to the markers-line, but you have only 4 possible weights for the series-line.
And if you ever need to hide the series line (keeping the markers-line visible), just add the next code before "End with":

```
   .Border.LineStyle = xlNone
```

Comment: border can be like `.Border.Weight = 3`

Comment: Thanks shihs! `xlThin` is just an alias for some specific numeric value, so using `.Border.Weight = 3` or `.Border.Weight = xlThin` has no bearing on the root cause/mechanism of the problem

Answer (score -2):

```
Dim co As ChartObject
Dim c As Chart
Dim s As Series
Dim p As Point

Set co = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
Set c = co.Chart
Set s = c.SeriesCollection(1)
Set p = s.Points(1)
p.Format.Line.Weight = 3
```

Comment: This code works for the first point (only). Change s.Points(1) to s.Points(3), it will change the line around point 3, AND the line from point 2 to point 3. Apparently, a "point" is the point itself, and the line segment connecting it to the previous point. Since the first point doesn't have a previous point, this code "works" on the first point only.

Comment: @Knom: Interesting. I didn't know that and only tested on the first point. Thanks for letting me know.